# How can I access an object property named as a variable in php?

Tags: php, json, google-api

A Google APIs encoded in JSON returned an object such as this

```
[updated] => stdClass Object
(
 [$t] => 2010-08-18T19:17:42.026Z
)
```

Anyone knows how can I access the `$t` value?

`$object->$t` obviously returns

> Notice: Undefined variable: `t` in /usr/local/...
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /....

Answer (score 269, accepted):

Since the name of your property is the string `'$t'`, you can access it like this:

```
echo $object->{'$t'};
```

Alternatively, you can put the name of the property in a variable and use it like this:

```
$property_name = '$t';
echo $object->$property_name;
```

You can see both of these in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/SpiritedTroubledWorkspace

Comment: What if simply "echo $object->$property_name" is used without the quotes. Seems to be working, but is it for newer php versions only?

Comment: @Larry In the OP's case the quotes are needed because `$t` *is* the name of property, not a variable *containing* the name of the property.

Comment: Four years later I've realized that I misread @Lamy comment. You're exactly right, Lamy. If the value of `$property_name` is the string `'$t'` then `echo $object->$property_name` works fine. I've updated my answer. Thanks and apologies!

Comment: Hello. I could use this answer but only with double quotes, @JordanRunning - are you sure it's right with single quotes?

Answer (score 33):

Correct answer (also for PHP7) is:

```
$obj->{$field}
```

Comment: What if the variable is only part of the property name? Is there a way to do something like `$obj->{"$field".'_id'}` for example?

Comment: Just discovered this is absolutely possible with `$obj->{"{$field}".'id'}`. It looks horrible but it 100% works.

Comment: This answer is totally wrong for the question.

Answer (score 20):

Have you tried:

```
$t = '$t'; // Single quotes are important.
$object->$t;
```

Comment: Documented behaviour: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php There are some important notes, read it ;)

Answer (score 8):

I'm using php7 and the following works fine for me:

```
class User {
    public $name = 'john';
}
$u = new User();

$attr = 'name';
print $u->$attr;
```

Answer (score 1):

this works on php 5 and 7

```
$props=get_object_vars($object);
echo $props[$t];
```