# How do you access a dynamic property in an object?

Tags: php, dynamic-properties

I am casting an array as an object and attempting to access the key (or property), but it is not working. The below code returns `type 8 -- Undefined property: stdClass::$2`. I attempted to use `property_exists()`, but that also failed.

```
$var = (object)array('1' => 'Object one','2' => 'Object two');
$num = "2";
var_dump( $var->$num );
```

Does anyone know why?

UPDATE: This seems to be an issue regardless if the properties are strings or integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access an object property named as a variable in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515861/how-can-i-access-an-object-property-named-as-a-variable-in-php)

Comment: the problem is the numeric key/propertyname. If you name it "a2" it'll work with your code: https://3v4l.org/JiU9A

Comment: @PranavCBalan I doubt this is a dupe, because the answers in the poss dupe will not work - (except in php >7.2): `$var->{$num}`

Comment: @Jeff :  yes you are right...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object properties with names like integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work in PHP < 7.2.0 and the issue is that the string-integer array keys are actually converted to integer property names, not strings.  An alternate way to get an object from an array that will work:

```
$var = json_decode(json_encode(array('1' => 'Object one','2' => 'Object two')));
$num = "2";
var_dump( $var->$num );
```

See the [Demo](https://3v4l.org/YU2Fo), in PHP < 7.2.0 the `(object)` cast converts to integer properties but `json_decode` creates string properties.