# Define properties of a class

Tags: php

Is there any way to define the properties of a class generic? To be more specific can I have let's say a file with define statement e.g.

```
define('USER_ID', 'userId')
```

and a class

```
foo{$userId}
```

How can I access the property like

```
$foo->USER_ID
```

?

Is there any way to achieve something like the above?

Thanks

Comment: What you want is called [variable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515861/how-can-i-access-an-object-property-named-as-a-variable-in-php) and the syntax is `$foo->{USER_ID}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use class constant :

```php
<?php
class Demo {
  const USER_ID = 3;
}

echo Demo::USER_ID;
?>
```

Comment: yes - as documented here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php