# Lavavel Undefined Variable in ::find() when editing existing posts

Tags: php, laravel, post, laravel-7

I created a function to edit existing posts on my laravel site. However the site is erroring when i try to submit to it. Its declaring an **Undefined variable: slug** Which if you see my example underneath it doesn't make sense since the the response from my Post log shows the variable in the object file.

```
 public function adminEditPostsPost(Request $request)
     {


        $user = Auth::user()->first();
        // Log::info($request->all());

        $update = false;

       // $token = $request->_token;
        $token = $request->session()->token();

          $postId = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-id');
          $title = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-title');
          $overview = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-overview');
          $post_status = $request->input('pxp-submit-post-status');
          //$images_array = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-images-array');
          $photo = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-photo-featured');

          // Log::info($slug);

        $id = $postId;
        $prop_id = 0;

        if ($request->is('admin/*')) {

               $posts = Posts::find($postId);               
               $posts->$title = $title;
               Log::info($posts);
               $posts->$slug = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-slug');
               $posts->$content = $overview;
               $posts->$featured_url = $photo;
               $posts->$post_status = $post_status;
                

                $posts->save();
         
            }


        $photos = Photos::where('enabled', '<=', '4')->get()->sortByDesc("created_at");
        $posts = Posts::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->where('post_status', '<=', '1')->get();

        return view('admin.posts')->with('photos', $photos)->with('posts', $posts);


     }
```

Here is The Log of the post variable:

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "slug": "two-homes-now-under-construction-for-late-spring-move-in-dates",
  "title": "Two Homes NOW Under Construction for Late Spring Move-in Dates",
  "featured_url": "146",
  "content": "<p></p>",
  "excerpt": null,
  "category": null,
  "tags": null,
  "created_at": "2021-02-16T15:49:44.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-16T15:49:44.000000Z",
  "post_status": "1",
  "Two Homes NOW Under Construction for Late Spring Move-in Dates": "Two Homes NOW Under Construction for Late Spring Move-in Dates"
}
```

At the bottom of the object i noticed that it had "Two Homes NOW Under Construction for Late Spring Move-in Dates" as a key which doesn't make sense to me i'm wondering if something is saving in my code that shouldn't have or how thats even being put in there in the first place since its not in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$title` variable is contains `notVariable` that make `$posts->$title` equivalen to `$posts->notVariable`. So you just need to remove `$` on `$posts` key/attribute.

change

```
$posts->$title = $title;
Log::info($posts);
$posts->$slug = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-slug');
$posts->$content = $overview;
$posts->$featured_url = $photo;
$posts->$post_status = $post_status;
```

to

```
$posts->title = $title;
Log::info($posts);
$posts->slug = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-slug');
$posts->content = $overview;
$posts->featured_url = $photo;
$posts->post_status = $post_status;
```

Comment: Literally today i noticed i had added $ to the object type. This is what i get for coding a midnight haha Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

PHP allows for the use of [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as well as using variables as object keys (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515861/how-can-i-access-an-object-property-named-as-a-variable-in-php) post for more explanation). You appear to be unintentionally incorporating this principle.

Before the `Log::info()` statement you are setting

```php
$posts->$title = $title
```

In PHP this is actually setting the key as `$title`s value which explains the "Two Homes NOW Under Construction for Late Spring Move-in Dates" key in your object. You aren't getting an **Undefined variable** error for `$title` because that variable exists. You are getting the **Undefined variable: slug** error because you are attempting to use the variables `$slug`, `$content`, etc. which do not exist to set the other keys. You need to  update your code to remove the `$` after the arrow.

```php
$posts->title = $title;
$posts->slug = $request->input('pxp-submit-comm-slug');
$posts->content = $overview;
$posts->featured_url = $photo;
$posts->post_status = $post_status;
```